# GSM 7600 Series AT Command (CEREG)

Tags: networking, mobile, gsm, 4g

I'm tryin to connect my GSM to network and I got the following response
+CEREG: 3
*REJCAUSE:0,0,15

Does anyone know what is rejection cause mean or any suggestions for solve it

I trying to connect to the 4G network
it was working will in my country and when I travel the above error appear